# Analyticity of $\dfrac{1}{z}$ vs. $\dfrac{1}{z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I am learning complex analysis on my own. I am familiar with the theorems, and I am able to compute by hand and get correct results. But there is something that escapes me.
What is the criteria for analyticity?

For example:
derivative if $\dfrac{1}{z}=-\dfrac{1}{z^2}$
derivative of $\dfrac{1}{z^2}=-\dfrac{2}{z^3}$

Both derivatives are undefined at $z=0$. Yet closed curve integral of $1/z !=0$, while $1/z^2$ does.
Cauchy integral theorem states that closed curve integrals of all analytic functions $=0.$

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ResidueTheorem.html

It states that (integral of) all the terms in a Laurent series besides $a_{-1} =0$ because of the Cauchy integral theorem.

I get the same correct results, computing these by hand. But I would like to understand, why all $1/z^n$ where $n=-1$ closed curve integrals $=0$ due to Cauchy integral theorem. They all have poles at $z=0$. And Cauchy integral theorem is suposed to apply only to curves not containg any poles(in the area they enclose).

I hope I was clear enough in my wording, if not, please say so.

Post-Acceptance-Edit:

Confusion arose, at their (sites') statement that Cauchys' theorem is the reason for the integral being zero, when that in fact is not true, as confirmed by other users.

Comment: Cauchy's integral theorem is concerned with curves (or systems of curves) that do not wind around any point in the complement of the domain of the analytic function. If you integrate over a closed curve $\gamma$ that doesn't wind around $0$, then you also have $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z} = 0$. The integral theorem says nothing about integrals over curves winding around $0$ (for $f(z) = z^{-k},\; k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
If you look at the link I posted, to the residue theorem on mathworld;

It's for curves enclosing z0, which is a pole for all terms (for n<0). Would you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: The residue theorem is more general than Cauchy's integral theorem. The CIT is the special case of the residue theorem where the curve (more generally, the cycle) doesn't wind around any point where the integrand isn't analytic (in particular, doesn't wind around any pole).

Comment: [mathjax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Nilan, thank you for the edit and the link.

Daniel Fischer:


The thing I'm struggling with, is why is it stated that all the terms besides a-1 are 0, due to Cauchy integral theorem, when the curve encloses the pole z0.
When I compute, I get the same results, I just don't understand their reasoning ( saying that the integrals of all terms are 0 due to CIT)
And thank you for your time.

Comment: Okay, I now looked at the page: It's wrong. For $n \geqslant 0$, the CIT implies the vanishing of the integral, but not for $n < -1$. As TorsionSquid said, the reason is that $z^{-n}$ has a primitive on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ for $n \geqslant 2$, and so the vanishing of the integral follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Thank you for your time Daniel. I was really bothered with my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that 
$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z^n} \, dz = 0, \:\: n=2,3,4\dots$$
But the reason is NOT Cauchy's Theorem.  For, as you said, these functions are not analytic in the unit disk.  One reason for the above is that $z^{-n}$ has an analytic primitive (antiderivative) along the unit circle, unless $n=1$.

Comment: Thank you for our reply. You and Daniel above helped me with my confusion, which turned out to be a mistake in the article I was reading (for what I wasn't confident enough to conclude on my own).

Answer (score 1):

The Laurent series of $\frac1{z^n}$ is $$ 0+\frac 0z+\frac 0{z^2}+\ldots +\frac 0{z^{n-1}}+\frac1{z^n}+\frac 0{z^{n+1}}+\ldots$$
so the only nonzero coefficient is $a_{-n}$. Hence the coefficient $a_{-1}$ that the Cuachy integral measeres is nonzero iff $n=1$.

Comment: Perhaps I've worded it badly. Would you mind explaining why the integral of 1/(z-z0)^2 over a curve enclosing z0 equal 0. 

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ResidueTheorem.html

As stated here, all terms are 0 due to Cauhy's integral theorem. 
But the curve encloses z0, and C.I.T. is supposed to hold for curves not enclosing poles.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having here with your curve integral is that Cauchy Integral theorem requires the function to be analytic on region inside the curve. But these functions are **not** analytic at origin.

Note also that the converse is not true, just because the integral vanishes doesn't mean that the function is analytic in the region inside as for example the example $f(z) = z^{-2}$

The definition for analyticity is in general that the function is possible to express as a power series (it doesn't have to be a complex function of a complex variable). At the level of basic complex analysis it's sometimes defined as being differentiable, but I'd recommend against it as a definition (as it only works out in that context).

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Wolfram-site states that the reason for the integral being zero, is Cauchys' theorem. I thought that wasn't true, so I asked the question here, and people have confirmed that the statement is false. So, to say it again, because I know I worded it badly before... I knew why the integral was zero, the FALSE statement on wolfram (or maybe I understood it wrongly) confused me.
But thank you for not neglecting older questions, +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you change variables to $w=\frac{1}{z}$ then you end up with $\int z^{-n}dz$ becoming $-\int w^n \frac{dw}{w^2}=-\int w^{n-2}dw$ and hence, for each $n\geq 2$ this is analytic again.